# Split String on comma, except when in square bracket

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I want to split strings on commas but ignore every match when the comma is between square brackets.

The following regex does work for general cases:

```
,(?![^\[\]]*+\\])
```

it works with:

```
TextA, TextB[cd,cd,c,]TextC, TextD
```

result:

```
"TextA"," TextB[cd,cd,c,]TextC"," TextD"
```

but will fail to split for the below case:

```
abc,]def
```

Actual result:

```
"abc,]def","",""
```

Expected result:

```
"abc","]def",""
```

Note: the regex should split both strings correctly

I was able to escape comma between square brackets with `,(?![^\[\]]*+\\])` but this regex fails when only a closing bracket was present in the string.

Comment: Regular expressions are really poor for this kind of thing.

Comment: In PCRE, you can use `(\[(?:[^][]++|(?1))*])(*SKIP)(*F)|,`, see https://regex101.com/r/sYBni2/2

Comment: What is your regex flavor?

Answer (score -1):

Instead of splitting you could *match* e.g.

```
(?:\[[^\]\[]*\]|[^,])+
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/V6WHb0/2) (the `\n` in demo are just for not skipping lines)

The left part of the [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) will match balanced brackets, the right part [non](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated)-commas.
You will need to additionally trim any white-space from the matches if this is wanted.